# appengine tasks work in developement, but not on server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have small application with a backend of appengine.
I want to merge duplicates in my database and doing it in a taskqueue:

```
    class MergeDuplicatesHandler(write_page.Handler):
        def get(self):
            self.render("mergeduplicateshandler.html")
        def post(self):
            adminpassword = self.request.get("adminpassword")
            if adminpassword == secret.ADMINPASSWORD:
                # Add the task to the default queue.
                taskqueue.add(url='/merge_duplicates', params={'adminpassword': adminpassword})

                self.redirect('/')
            else:
                self.response.out.write("Wrong password")

    class MergeDuplicates(write_page.Handler):
        def post(self):
            adminpassword = self.request.get("adminpassword")
            if adminpassword == secret.ADMINPASSWORD:
                 person_service.merge_duplicates()
```

`write_page.Handler` is a webapp2 handler

edit:

this is my merge_duplicates function:

```
def merge_duplicates():
    people = get_all()
    peopletodelete = []
    count = 0
    for p1 in people:
        deleted = False
        if p1.cellphone != "" and p1.cellphone is not None:
            for pdel in peopletodelete:
                if(p1.key().id() == pdel.key().id()):
                    deleted = True
            if not deleted:
                p1people = get_people_by_cellphone(p1.cellphone)
                if p1people:
                    for p2 in p1people:
                        if(p1.key().id() != p2.key().id()):
                            p1 = merge_person(p1,p2)
                            try:
                                insert_or_update_person(p1.firstname,
                                                p1.secondfirstname,
                                                p1.lastname,
                                                p1.secondlastname,
                                                p1.cellphone,
                                                p1.shortcellphone,
                                                p1.workphone,
                                                p1.secondworkphone,
                                                p1.homephone,
                                                p1.email,
                                                p1.homenumber,
                                                p1.workernum,
                                                p1.username,
                                                p1.password)
                                peopletodelete.append(p2)
                            count = count + 1
                                # logging.info("Merge Dups Inserting: {0}".format(p1.firstname))
                            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                                logging.error("Problem with: {0} {1}".format(p1.firstname,p1.lastname))
        else:
                # logging.info("Merge Dups Deleting: {0}".format(p1.firstname))
                p1.delete()
    for pdel in peopletodelete:
        pdel.delete()
    return count

def merge_person(p1,p2):
    p1.firstname = merge_person_parameter(p1.firstname,p1.last_modified,p2.firstname,p2.last_modified)
    p1.secondfirstname = merge_person_parameter(p1.secondfirstname,p1.last_modified,p2.secondfirstname,p2.last_modified)
    p1.lastname = merge_person_parameter(p1.lastname,p1.last_modified,p2.lastname,p2.last_modified)
    p1.secondlastname = merge_person_parameter(p1.secondlastname,p1.last_modified,p2.secondlastname,p2.last_modified)
    p1.cellphone = merge_person_parameter(p1.cellphone,p1.last_modified,p2.cellphone,p2.last_modified)
    p1.shortcellphone = merge_person_parameter(p1.shortcellphone,p1.last_modified,p2.shortcellphone,p2.last_modified)
    p1.workphone = merge_person_parameter(p1.workphone,p1.last_modified,p2.workphone,p2.last_modified)
    p1.secondworkphone = merge_person_parameter(p1.secondworkphone,p1.last_modified,p2.secondworkphone,p2.last_modified)
    p1.homephone = merge_person_parameter(p1.homephone,p1.last_modified,p2.homephone,p2.last_modified)
    p1.email = merge_person_parameter(p1.email,p1.last_modified,p2.email,p2.last_modified)
    p1.homenumber = merge_person_parameter(p1.homenumber,p1.last_modified,p2.homenumber,p2.last_modified)
    p1.workernum = merge_person_parameter(p1.workernum,p1.last_modified,p2.workernum,p2.last_modified)
    p1.username = merge_person_parameter(p1.username,p1.last_modified,p2.username,p2.last_modified)
    p1.password =         merge_person_parameter(p1.password,p1.last_modified,p2.password,p2.last_modified)
    return p1


 def merge_person_parameter(param1,modified1,param2,modified2) :
    if not param1:
        if param2:
            param1 = param2
    if param1:
        if param2:
            if modified1 < modified2:
                param1 = param2
    return param1
```

All of this works perfectly in development on localhost. I upload it to appengine. It runs the task, I see it running and does absolutely nothing.
Is it just taking a long time or something?

Comment: Could you post the code or describe what you do in person_service.merge_duplicates()?

Comment: just added the merger duplicates function, it works perfectly in developement but does nothing on the appengine

Comment: Seems like you're trying to modify the datastore by iterating through each record, which is almost always a bad idea on GAE, unless you have a tiny data set. This kind of task is more suited for MapReduce: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/

Comment: I will try mapreduce, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add logs to your process and check app engine logs in the developer console.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging

Comment: I did it but I don't see all the logs I put in. I found something in the logs though: This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Comment: - You have to expand the log entry to see all the logs.
- "This request may thus take longer" means one second longer, not much more.